# iPhone GameKit Picker Fundamental Connection Issues

Tags: iphone, gamekit

This is one of the more interesting things I've seen in iPhone development.

The following question has nothing to do with code because I'm using an SDK Example from Apple (Tanks example).

I have a 3GS iPhone, and a 3G iPhone both showing the GameKit picker screen.  Both will eventually show the other phone in range just fine (It does take about 25 seconds, though).

If I pick the 3G iPhone with my 3GS, the 3G will get a connection request and a connection can be made.  However, it will ABSOLUTELY not work in the vice versa.  Both phones have bluetooth switched on, and both phones are running the latest OS version.

The simple fact is I'm using the SDK example, and it's just not working for the 3G trying to issue the connection.  Is there any way to explain this extremely odd behavior?

Thanks alot for reading!

Comment: Just to clarify, both phones have been rebooted, clean installs have been made with the example, multiple codebases have been used, multiple updates have been given to both devices.  This behavior has gone on for over 5 months so far.

Comment: I can connect with a 3G, but the connection can drop easily and unexpectedly. So yeah, it's Apple's fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the same problem, intermittently though. I don't think it's that odd because the 3G and 3GS actually use different Bluetooth tech. IMO, the Bluetooth on iPhone just isn't there yet.

Comment: Ah!  It's good there's someone to verify this atleast.   Thanks.  At this point I'm wondering if I should release the app given that it's just Apple's fault.  I just don't want it to reflect badly on me, you know?

I sort of wonder if its a protocol problem with Bonjour or something, or strictly hardware related as you mentioned.